# Snapframework routes from 'csv'

Tags: haskell, tuples, monads, haskell-snap-framework

i am not sure if i should use `eval` for this but i want to dynamically load the routes in a `SnapFramework` from a `csv` file, like this:

```
csv file

route, file
redirect, redirects.csv
red, redirects2.csv
```

Now, i want to say to the framework which file should read in which ocasion

```
hs file

start = do
    snapRoutes <- readCsv "routes.csv"

rut a = ((fst a ++ "/:md5"), redirectTo (snd a))

skite :: Snap ()
skite =
    ifTop noHandler <|>
    route (mapM_ rut start) <|>
    fourOhFour
```

Now i want to inject the following `Snap monad` in the `tuple` needed for routes and it seems i can't figure out how. Can `liftM` or `unsafeEval` solve the problem? And how?

```
redirectTo :: String -> Snap()
redirectTo fileName = do
    param <- getParam "md5"
    redirects <- liftIO $ readCsv fileName
    theParam <- maybe (return "oh no")
                    return param
    writeBS redirects
```

Or any other ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand your question in enough detail to answer it here.  It might be helpful to have a more in-depth conversation about this in IRC.  Try the #snapframework channel on Freenode.  There are a number of people there who might be able to help you.